# Verb for "turning a bug into an attack"?

Tags: exploit, terminology

I forget what word it is that refers to the work of turning known bugs into real-world attacks, for example when [people string together two separate exploits to break out of the Chrome sandbox](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/05/09/google_chrome_pwned/). It's not "weaponize", it's not "exploitize", what is it again?

Comment: [exploit?](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exploit_1)

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to bug chaining?

Comment: @wireghoul that was it I think. Also maybe something being "wormable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug can be seen as a vulnerability which once 'attacked' is being exploited.

If a number of vulnerabilities are exploited by a bad actor together as part of a wider attacker this commonly called a chained exploit.

If you mean about the breaking out of a VM attack then they can be referred to as a "virtual machine escape" exploit.